# Exclude 0 size files

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

How to grep excluding 0 size files in shell scripting?

My code is,

```
grep -lri "pattern" "path_to_folder" | while temp_var= read -r file; do cp "$file" folder_to_copy
```

In this i have to ignore 0bytes files/empty files

Comment: The thing is, `grep pattern` could not find a pattern in an empty file, right? ...

Answer (score 4):

If a file contains `pattern` then this file isn't empty, so you don't have anything to do to ignore 0 bytes files

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Not sure why still the file size is 0

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -lri "pattern" "path_to_folder" | while read -r file; do
    if [ -s $file ]; then
         cp "$file" folder_to_copy
    fi
done
```

explanation: `[ -s $file ]` is true if file is not empty

Comment: `test -s` is the correct way to test if a file is empty, so +1

Comment: @Chris Maes [-s $..] is to check empty and so file will be zero bytes
logically its correct. 
in my case, it seems that pattern is present  inside that file and so it is displaying that file and copying
so in this case file is not empty